How do I reduce the power consuption of my 2011 iMac running Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS
I have already had great success with reducing the power consumption of this machine by blacklisting kernel modules and removing hardware(SD card reader, bluetooth card, mic, sound, camera, CD drive).
However, I would like to reduce power consumption even further.
Is there anything else I could do to reduce power consumption?
lsmod shows this:
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  6
qrtr                   53248  2
ip6t_REJECT            12288  1
nf_reject_ipv6         24576  1 ip6t_REJECT
xt_hl                  12288  22
ip6t_rt                16384  3
ipt_REJECT             12288  1
nf_reject_ipv4         12288  1 ipt_REJECT
xt_LOG                 16384  10
nf_log_syslog          20480  10
xt_comment             12288  4
xt_multiport           16384  4
nft_limit              16384  13
xt_limit               12288  0
xt_addrtype            12288  4
xt_tcpudp              16384  60
xt_conntrack           12288  16
nf_conntrack          196608  1 xt_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         12288  1 nf_conntrack
nft_compat             20480  125
nf_tables             372736  718 nft_compat,nft_limit
nls_iso8859_1          12288  1
input_leds             12288  0
apple_mfi_fastcharge    16384  0
ath9k                 253952  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      40960  1 intel_rapl_msr
ath9k_common           45056  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              663552  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    40960  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       24576  0
mac80211             1720320  1 ath9k
coretemp               24576  0
kvm_intel             487424  0
applesmc               28672  0
kvm                  1404928  1 kvm_intel
cfg80211             1323008  4 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath,mac80211
irqbypass              12288  1 kvm
mei_pxp                16384  0
mei_hdcp               28672  0
at24                   28672  0
mei_me                 53248  2
rapl                   20480  0
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
intel_cstate           24576  0
mei                   167936  5 mei_hdcp,mei_pxp,mei_me
i2c_i801               36864  0
lpc_ich                32768  0
i2c_smbus              16384  1 i2c_i801
acpi_als               16384  1
industrialio_triggered_buffer    12288  1 acpi_als
kfifo_buf              12288  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
industrialio          126976  3 industrialio_triggered_buffer,acpi_als,kfifo_buf
video                  73728  0
wmi                    28672  1 video
mac_hid                12288  0
binfmt_misc            24576  1
dm_multipath           45056  0
msr                    12288  0
efi_pstore             12288  0
nfnetlink              20480  3 nft_compat,nf_tables
dmi_sysfs              24576  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               65536  13 xt_conntrack,nft_compat,xt_LOG,xt_multiport,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,ip6t_rt,xt_comment,ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,xt_limit,xt_hl,ip6t_REJECT
autofs4                57344  2
btrfs                2015232  0
blake2b_generic        24576  0
raid10                 73728  0
raid456               192512  0
async_raid6_recov      20480  1 raid456
async_memcpy           16384  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_pq               20480  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_xor              16384  3 async_pq,raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx               16384  5 async_pq,async_memcpy,async_xor,raid456,async_raid6_recov
xor                    20480  2 async_xor,btrfs
raid6_pq              126976  4 async_pq,btrfs,raid456,async_raid6_recov
libcrc32c              12288  4 nf_conntrack,btrfs,nf_tables,raid456
raid1                  57344  0
raid0                  24576  0
hid_apple              28672  0
hid_generic            12288  0
usbhid                 77824  0
hid                   180224  3 usbhid,hid_apple,hid_generic
crct10dif_pclmul       12288  1
crc32_pclmul           12288  0
polyval_clmulni        12288  0
polyval_generic        12288  1 polyval_clmulni
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
sha256_ssse3           32768  0
sha1_ssse3             32768  0
ahci                   49152  3
tg3                   229376  0
libahci                53248  1 ahci
aesni_intel           356352  4
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel

powertop shows this:
  Usage     Device name
394.4%        CPU core
394.4%        CPU misc
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Universal Host Controller #1
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Universal Host Controller #5
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
100.0%        PCI Device: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Z68 Express Chipset LPC Controller
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
100.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller
100.0%        PCI Device: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter
100.0%        Radio device: ath9k
 86.2%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
 77.5%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
  1.9 pkts/s  Network interface: wlp3s0 (ath9k)
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
  0.0%        runtime-alarmtimer.0.auto
  0.0%        USB device: IR Receiver (Apple Computer, Inc.)
  0.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
  0.0%        USB device: Apple Keyboard (Apple Inc.)
  0.0%        USB device: usb-device-0424-2514
  0.0%        USB device: UHCI Host Controller
  0.0%        USB device: UHCI Host Controller
  0.0%        USB device: EHCI Host Controller
  0.0%        USB device: Keyboard Hub (Apple Inc.)
  0.0%        USB device: usb-device-0424-2514
  0.0 pkts/s  Network interface: enp2s0 (tg3)
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
  0.0%        PCI Device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
  0.0%        runtime-reg-dummy
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation CV82524 Thunderbolt Controller [Light Ridge 4C 2010]
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
  0.0%        PCI Device: LSI Corporation FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
  0.0%        PCI Device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
  0.0%        runtime-simple-framebuffer.0
  0.0%        runtime-PNP0C0C:00
  0.0%        runtime-PNP0C09:00
  0.0%        runtime-Fixed MDIO bus.0
  0.0%        I2C Device (0-0053): spd
  0.0%        runtime-intel_rapl_msr.0
  0.0%        I2C Device (0-0051): spd
  0.0%        runtime-microcode
  0.0%        runtime-eisa.0
  0.0%        runtime-applesmc.768
  0.0%        runtime-acpi-cpufreq
  0.0%        runtime-kgdboc
  0.0%        runtime-APP0001:00
  0.0%        runtime-APP0002:00
  0.0%        runtime-PNP0C0E:00
  0.0%        runtime-pcspkr
  0.0%        runtime-ACPI0008:00
  0.0%        runtime-rtc-efi.0
  0.0%        runtime-INT0800:00
  0.0%        runtime-coretemp.0
  0.0%        runtime-regulatory.0
  0.0%        I2C Adapter (i2c-0): SMBus I801 adapter at efa0
  0.0%        runtime-APP000C:00
  0.0%        runtime-iTCO_wdt.1.auto
  0.0%        runtime-serial8250
  0.0%        runtime-efivars.0
  0.0%        runtime-PNP0C04:00

